# Django admin display field of related model in Inline

Tags: python, django, admin

I want to display the value of a field belonging to a related model insida an inline. Is this possible?

```
#models.py GroupInviteTracking
httprequest_data = models.ForeginKey(HTTPRequestData)

#admin.py Inline of GroupInviteTracking
fieldsets = (
    ("HTTPRequestData", {
        'fields': (
            "httprequest_data__user",
            "httprequest_data__ip",
        ),
    }),
)
```